# Intermittent internet connectivity problems on Samsung Galaxy S4

Tags: chrome-for-android, internet

So last night Chrome on my Galaxy S4 suddenly started refusing to load websites while connected to the exact same WiFi network that works flawlessly for two different laptops and a PC within my home network. Even using two different mobile providers' data networks, or the WiFi at three different friends' houses doesn't seem to work, so I doubt this issue has anything to do with my internet connection/s.

The strangest thing about this whole situation is that Chrome will search Google fine, and the Play store app will also search its catalog, download updates and even install new apps without a hitch, but pretty much every time I try to connect to a non-Google-owned server, the connection status bar fills about 10% of the way and hangs for 30 seconds before timing out.

Has anyone experienced anything like this before?

EDIT: This now happens at least once per day; often 3 or 4 times per day. Restarting the phone seems to be the only way to get connectivity back, before it drops out again a few hours later. Google apps (Play Store, YouTube, Maps, etc.) all work fine without a restart but other apps and websites refuse to respond. Please help; this is driving me crazy!!